# Rendering a PDF from HTML that refers to another PDF as an <object> tag

Tags: python, pdf, playwright

I have a generated HTML page that might include images or references to PDF pages. I would like to convert that HTML to PDF and include the referenced PDF files in the generated PDF using Playwright for Python.

An example:

```
<html>
<body>
    <h1>Hello World</h1>
    <p>The following PDF should be inserted inline</p>
    <figure>
      <object data="file:///path/to/file.pdf" type=application/pdf width="100%" height="500px">
        <embed type="application/pdf" src="file:///path/to/file.pdf" />
      </object>
    </figure>
    <p>There might be other content, images or PDFs</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Is this even possible or do I have to render the PDF separately? When I try it using the Playwright for Python it generates a message "Couldn't load plugin." instead of the  tag.

Comment: You should use the pdf in Base64 I guess

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There can be problems rendering a PDF from a Browser via external means , however if you simply run them internally first you can see what will be top of your expectations.

So since it is easiest for me, here is the best Acrobatic Edge offering (and thus all others can only try to match it).

[image]

What you should note is that the Chromium Skia PDF writer has done an excellent job converting HTML to PDF vector paths and also converting the body text into embedded text.

For the Acrobat Viewport it has taken a snapshot and then overlaid all those browsing icons and lines as overlaid PDF paths totally worthless as it adds to the bloat and nothing that is not there when top bar is autohidden! but it is 100% authentic to include them.

And what about that PDF in the middle ? Well Firefox, Google Docs, MS Live Online, etc. will replace with an image and we can see that's what happens here, with the Acrobat rendering by Skia.

[image]

So to bypass all those problems, simply use an embedded image for each page. NOTE there are other issues such as, why was the embedded PDF in the view ports above showing Sans Serif when Page1 text is clearly seen here as Times Roman (but that's a different PDF question.)

[image]

Comment: Embedding the PDF as images seems to be the most reasonable solution. Thank you